# W3C Notification Coverage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, code-coverage, karma-jasmine, cobertura

I'm having trouble getting my Code Coverage to 100% due to the W3C Notification not being available for PhantomJS. I have the following function:

```
function requirespermission(overwrite){
    if(overwrite || (typeof Notification !== 'undefined' && Notification.permission === 'granted'))
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else if(!overwrite || typeof Notification !== 'undefined'){
        Notification.requestPermission();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and my tests are the following:

```
it('should be able to get permission', function(){
    notificationservice.requirespermission(true);
});

it('should be able to not get permission', function(){
    notificationservice.requirespermission(false);
});
```

but whatever I do, the condition coverage of the else function stays at 2/4 (which makes sense, but I have to implement the check for cross-browser support). I use the following tools:

- Karma + Jasmine for the tests
- karma-coverage for the coverage
- PhantomJS as the unit test browser
- Cobertura as reporter
- (Jenkins as CI)

How can I get the else function to pass the code coverage tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using a wrapper around Notifications by using [Notify.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js). Code now is:

```
function requirespermission(overwrite){
    if(!Notify.needsPermission || overwrite)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else if(Notify.isSupported()){  
        Notify.requestPermission();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the tests:

```
it('should be able to not get permission', function(){
    notificationservice.requirespermission(true);
});

it('should be able to not get permission', function(){
    spyOn(Notify, 'isSupported').and.returnValue(true);
    notificationservice.requirespermission(false);
});

it('should handle not-supported', function(){
    spyOn(Notify, 'isSupported').and.returnValue(false);
    notificationservice.requirespermission(false);
});
```